# ConvertHexToWideString - reverse function

Tags: delphi-7

I am using this function and need reverse one. Its converting HEX (unicode) string to unicode (WideString). I need reverse function to convert it back, i.e. Widestring back to HEX (unicode).

```
function _ConvertHexToWideString(AHex: AnsiString): WideString;
var wBinaryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin

  try
    wBinaryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
      wBinaryStream.Size := Length(AHex) div 2;

      if wBinaryStream.Size > 0 then
        HexToBin(PAnsiChar(AHex), wBinaryStream.Memory, wBinaryStream.Size);
    except
    end;
    SetString(Result, 
              PWideChar(wBinaryStream.Memory), 
              wBinaryStream.Size div SizeOf(WideChar));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(wBinaryStream);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I guess you missed the link to [BinToHex](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.BinToHex) in the help file where you found `HexToBin`. The link is to the XE3 documentation, but they're basically the same, and there's a code example linked at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks Ken, it helped :) I just needed to modify it little bit. You`re boss :)

Comment: You can't type-cast a `WideString` to a `PAnsiChar`.  Type-cast the `WideString` to a `Pointer` first, then type-cast that to `PAnsiChar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply do the opposite, using `BinToHex()` instead, eg:

```
function _ConvertWideStringToHex(AStr: WideString): AnsiString;
var
  wBinaryStream: TMemoryStream;
  iBufSize: Integer;
begin
  try
    wBinaryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      iBufSize := Length(AStr) * SizeOf(WideChar);
      wBinaryStream.Size := iBufSize * 2;
      if iBufSize > 0 then
        BinToHex(PAnsiChar(Pointer(AStr)), PAnsiChar(wBinaryStream.Memory), iBufSize);
    except
    end;
    SetString(Result, 
              PAnsiChar(wBinaryStream.Memory), 
              wBinaryStream.Size div SizeOf(AnsiChar));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(wBinaryStream);
  end;
end;
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```
function _ConvertWideStringToHex(AStr: WideString): AnsiString;
var
  iBufSize: Integer;
begin
  iBufSize := Length(AStr) * SizeOf(WideChar);
  if iBufSize > 0 then begin
    SetLength(Result, iBufSize * 2);
    BinToHex(PAnsiChar(Pointer(AStr)), PAnsiChar(Result), iBufSize);
  end else
    Result := '';
end;
```